# Monitoring Multiple channels in asterisk at same time

Tags: asterisk

Sorry because my English is not as good,

i am developing a monitoring application which is basically a soft phone on manager desk which monitor multiple channels (remote phones) at once 
Manager Application has my custom based desktop application which passes Sip Messages to asterisk 
e.g

i treat Manager Application as a Sip client (a simple soft phone with maximum access)

i have M1 as (First Manager Application )
R1,R2,R3,R4 ....... so on (Multiple Remote phones or channels registered on asterisk)
i want to monitor R1,R2 at same time from M1
R1 talks to M1
R2 talks to M1
but R1 and R2 are not allowed to talk to each other,

For that purpose i used ChanSpy but it monitor only one chanel at a time
than i designed to use Conference Room 1  for R1 and Conference room 2 for  R2 and tried to join both with the help of that link

but i got background noise in this scenario

Join two conferences in asterisk - Stack Overflow
Join two conferences in asterisk - Stack Overflow
considering you have two conferences rooms named 1 and 2 then add to your extensions.conf: [join-conference] exten => s,1,ConfBridge(2) exten => s,n,Hangup exten => h,1,Hangip and do it in shell:
View on stackoverflow.com
Preview by Yahoo

but i got background noise in this scenario which increases when i join multiple times,
my local channels stay active if i hangup my remote phones. i think reason for noise is active local channels

Kindly give me some guide line how i can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

More channels give more noise.

You can do nothign here.

Every single channel have noise. When you bridge it you have noise from ALL channels combined.

Comment: Any other way for handling this in asterisk any other design or something,

Comment: because we have multiple Managers and they all have to monitor same number of channels,

Comment: I already describe what i can. If you have two channel, one have noise every 2 sec, other every 2 sec, then in average you will have noise every 1 sec if conferencing both. It is not asterisk's problem. It is source microphone problem.

Answer (score 0):

We use a GUI for call center (QueueMetrics) and our ops do the chanspy in sequence from there. It is easy to skip from one agent to the other in sequence.

Comment: appreciate your reply @FrankZee :)
but i want to monitor multiple agents at same time its my project requirement and i did't find any way to do that as i am new in asterisk so kindly guide me that this thing is achieved by asterisk or not !